# angular 1, ui-router 1 execute two from

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, template-literals

This code allows me to execute $ transitions if the page is "production.contact.create"

```
  .run(($transitions, Toast) => {
    'ngInject'
    $transitions.onSuccess({
      from: 'production.contact.create'
    }
```

I would like to run this code in two pages, "production.contact.create" and "production.contact.detail, Something like that :

```
  .run(($transitions, Toast) => {
    'ngInject'
    $transitions.onSuccess({
      from: 'production.contact.create',
      from: 'production.contact.detail'
    }
```

Is there a solution ? With Template Literals for example